# Multiple table-based replacement in a SQL function

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

I need to create a function that performs multiple replacements in a string based on a lookup table. However, the result is always the last replacement as if the previous replacements don't happen. The identical stored procedure provides the correct result.

Here is my function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION tmp.fix_template_list_data_test 
    (@source varchar(max))
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @source = REPLACE(@source, longer, shorter)
    FROM tmp.vaccine_replacements
    ORDER BY id

    RETURN @source
END
```

This is on SQL Server.

Comment: Proptip: don't forget `SCHEMABINDING`, otherwise your `FUNCTION` might unexpectedly stop working if you make a table design change.

Comment: What DBMS is this request about? SQL Server? Please tag your request accodingly.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: `The identical stored procedure provides the correct result.` if it does, it's probably an accident. SQL is a set-based language and SELECT isn't a loop operator. The server is free to use whatever execution plan is fastest and cheapest. If there are a lot of rows, the server could partition the data and use multiple cores to process it. There's *no* expectation that `@source` will contain intermediate results, much less that the intermediate results from one core would pass to another core

Comment: This is not going to function as you are perhaps expecting, regardless of implementing as a function or a procedure; to do what you are expecting (in a set-based operation) you are going to require a recursive CTE.

Comment: that's one of the biggest downsides of sql server, multiple replaces are hard to achieve, you need some sort of loop, either cte, cursor or while.

Comment: You are using a variant of the anti pattern described here. Not guaranteed and execution plan dependent https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment

Comment: @siggemannen quite the opposite - what you claim as a SQL Server downside is one of *MySQL*'s worst bugs, which are semi-supported only because people got used to them. Sets have no order. SQL, the language, doesn't guarantee processing order. Parallelism can't work if you impose a processing order. *Hash joins* change the order. The only reason such quirky code works in MySQL is that historically the query optimizer wasn't that good and didn't use parallelism or sophisticated strategies. MySQL frequently suffers performance regressions even among minor versions due to those quirks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, i think an aggregate function like REPLACE_AGG(stringToReplace, colReplace, colValue) WITHIN GROUP (order by somesort) would be possible to add to sql server. I agree one shouldn't use quirky updates and other bad means to do it.

Comment: Can we assume any upper limit to the number of replacements that the table will contain?

Comment: Weird, I'm using `SELECT @str = @str + some_column FROM some_table ORDER BY id` in many places and it never fails @PanagiotisKanavos @Stu

Comment: @ulu people that use NOLOCK claim the same - until they get hit by the bugs. Performance of this quirky call is very bad, [7-20 times slower](https://sqlblog.org/2011/03/08/t-sql-tuesday-16-this-is-not-the-aggregate-youre-looking-for) than the FOR XML code used before STRING_AGG, which is [2-5 times faster than FOR XML](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/12/sql-performance/sql-server-v-next-string_agg-performance). You end up with 14-100 times worse performance. Essentially, you're using a cursor indirectly which means the server can't use any optimizations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/K80HOOfs).

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION /*tmp*/dbo.fix_template_list_data_test( @source nvarchar(max) )
RETURNS nvarchar(max) WITH SCHEMABINDING, RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS
BEGIN

    -- This FUNCTION makes a private copy of the replacements table to ensure ordering and to prevent taking excessive locks on the source table.
    DECLARE @replacements TABLE (
        Ordinal     int           NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        ReplaceThis nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
        WithThis    nvarchar(max) NOT NULL
    );

    INSERT INTO @replacements ( Ordinal, ReplaceThis, WithThis )
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY id ) AS Ordinal,
        longer  AS ReplaceThis,
        shorter AS WithThis
    FROM
        /*tmp*/dbo.vaccine_replacements;

    DECLARE @mutable nvarchar(max) = @source;

    DECLARE @i   int = 1;
    DECLARE @max int = ( SELECT MAX( Ordinal ) FROM @replacements );
    WHILE( @i <= @max )
    BEGIN
        SET @mutable = ( SELECT TOP 1 REPLACE( @mutable, ReplaceThis, WithThis ) FROM @replacements WHERE Ordinal = @i );
        SET @i = @i + 1;
    END;

    RETURN @mutable;
END;
```

Proof:

```sql
CREATE TABLE /*tmp*/dbo.vaccine_replacements (
    id int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    longer  nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
    shorter nvarchar(max) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO /*tmp*/dbo.vaccine_replacements ( longer, shorter ) VALUES
( 'AAAAAA', 'A6' ),
( 'BBBBBB', 'B6' ),
( 'CCCCCC', 'C6' );

SELECT /*tmp*/dbo.fix_template_list_data_test( N'CCCCCCAAAAAABBBBBB' );

-- Outputs "C6A6B6"
```

The above `FUNCTION` uses `CURSOR`-style logic with a `WHILE()` loop - but that's okay because [using `WHILE` is superior to a `CURSOR` for situations like these](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6148/sql-server-loop-through-table-rows-without-cursor).

Comment: You'll have to benchmark this. When Aaron Bertrand compared loops, whiles and the SELECT trick [13 years ago](https://sqlblog.org/2011/03/08/t-sql-tuesday-16-this-is-not-the-aggregate-youre-looking-for) the SELECT trick, which also acts as a cursor, was faster than loops bug several times slower than FOR XML